# Scrapy returning empty lists when using css

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape nordstrom product descriptions. I got all the item links (stored in local mongodb db) and now am itertating through them and here is an example link https://www.nordstrom.ca/s/leith-ruched-body-con-tank-dress/5420732?origin=category-personalizedsort&breadcrumb=Home%2FWomen%2FClothing%2FDresses&color=001

My code for the spider is:

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = NordstromItem()
    description = response.css("div._26GPU").css("div::text").extract()
    items['description'] = description
    yield items
```

I also tried scrapy shell and the returned page is blank.
I am also using scrapy random agents.

Comment: “I also tried scrapy shell and the returned page is blank”. Sounds like you are getting detected as a bot and given a bad response. That’s what you need to fix first.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use css or xpath selector to get the info you want. Here's more about it: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

And you can also use css/xpath checker to help identify if the selector gets the info you want. Like this Chrome extesion: https://autonomiq.io/chropath/